# DKIM set on AWS EC2 but mail header says none in Outlook

Tags: amazon-ec2, postfix, email-server, dkim, opendkim

I'm configuring an AWS EC2 instance with Postfix, and have set it up with Route53 including reverse DNS. I've tested that I can send emails, and Outlook receives them fine, but Gmail does not. I followed [this guide](https://easyengine.io/tutorials/mail/setup-opendkim/) to install and configure opendkim, and when I use [this validator](https://www.dmarcanalyzer.com/dkim/dkim-check/), I get [this message stating that it's a valid DKIM record](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ccbhS.jpg). However, when I use [this validator](https://dkimvalidator.com/), I get the response that "This message does not contain a DKIM Signature". Furthermore, when I send the email to Outlook, it goes in the main inbox, but I get the following results from authentication:

```
Authentication-Results: spf=pass (sender IP is x.x.x.x)

 smtp.mailfrom=mail.example.com; mail.outlookserver.com; dkim=none (message not

 signed) header.d=none;mail.outlookserver.com; dmarc=pass action=none

 header.from=mail.example.com;compauth=pass reason=100
```

The IP address of `x.x.x.x` is a substitution for my mail server's IP address, and `mail.example.com` is the FQDN of my mail server. `mail.outlookserver.com` is the Outlook mail server. Evidently, the SPF and DMARC records pass, however the DKIM record does not. I have the DKIM record set in AWS Route 53 as shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mn3VX.jpg) and [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jYkAg.jpg), and I can do a dig and have it return the expected value, where `$key` is my public key:

```
andreaskralj@linuxdev:~$ dig +short TXT mail._domainkey.example.com
"v=DKIM1; h=sha256; k=rsa; " "p=$key"
```

I'm unsure why my DKIM record isn't perceived as valid by Outlook or the other validator. If anyone has any ideas of what I can try or needs any more information, please let me know.

**Edit:**

I tried to add the following lines in `/etc/postfix/master.cf`:

```
pickup    unix  n       -       y       60      1       pickup
  -o smtpd_milters=inet:localhost:8892
  -o non_smtpd_milters=inet:localhost:8892
```

The pickup line was already there; I added the -o lines according to the suggested answer by @Lasse Michael Mølgaard. Unfortunately, my email headers still say that the DKIM is set to none.

Comment: How are you sending and receiving emails? Are you using SMTP / Submission or ActiveSync for sending?

Comment: I'm not receiving any emails, I'm only sending them over SMTP using the linux mail utility. I'll run the following command: `echo "This is a test" | mail -s "Test Email" andreaskralj@emailaddr.com` and it'll be received in the default inbox in Outlook, however dkim will be set to "none"

Comment: Ah... That is problebly because even though `mail` is supposed to send via SMTP - it doesn't it uses `maildrop` which is then picked up by `pickup` deamon before it is fed to Postfix. I had same issue when getting mails from ActiveSync vs SMTP or Submission. Hence why I gave my hint. Sometimes it is really like taking a tumble "Alice in Wonderland"-style and see how far down the rabbit hole you fell.

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion based on my comment:

I use amavis to sign my mails, so I have added a line underneath the default pickup line with `-o content_filter=...`, so it now states.

```
pickup    unix  n       -       y       60      1       pickup
    -o content_filter=amavis:[127.0.0.1]:10026
```

Im wondering if you can use `smtpd_milters` and `non-smtpd_milters` the same way?

**EDIT**

If you want to use Amavis DKIM to sign mail, you need to tweak your master file a little more.

Default setting is when you forward something to Amavis (in my case port 10026) then Amavis will return the result using a port one higher (in my case 10027).

I therefore have the following entry in my `master.cf` file:

```
amavis unix - - y - 2 smtp
        -o smtp_data_done_timeout=1200
        -o smtp_send_xforward_command=yes
        -o smtp_bind_address=

127.0.0.1:10027 inet n - n - - smtpd
-o content_filter=
-o local_recipient_maps=
-o relay_recipient_maps=
-o smtpd_restriction_classes=
-o smtpd_client_restrictions=
-o smtpd_helo_restrictions=
-o smtpd_sender_restrictions=
-o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=permit_mynetworks,reject
-o mynetworks=127.0.0.0/8
-o strict_rfc821_envelopes=yes
-o receive_override_options=no_unknown_recipient_checks,no_header_body_checks
-o smtp_send_xforward_command=yes
-o milter_default_action=accept
-o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
-o disable_dns_lookups=yes
```

The way Amavis knows how to send the signed result back to Postfix is from this part in `/etc/amavis/conf.d/50-user`:

```
# :* = send to incoming Port + 1
$forward_method = 'smtp:127.0.0.1:*';
$notify_method = 'smtp:127.0.0.1:*';
$interface_policy{'10026'} = 'ORIGINATING';
$policy_bank{'ORIGINATING'} = {
  originating => 1,
};
```

[There is a very short signing example with Amavis here](https://nwgat.ninja/setting-up-dkim-and-spf-with-amavis-on-ubuntu-16-04-2/)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'll test it out and see if it worked.

Comment: Sorry it took me a bit to get back to you. I tried this, unfortunately it didn't work. I edited the question accordingly, please verify that the syntax I used is correct according to your suggestion.

Comment: Well I had issues using the milter approach too. Hence why I ended up using Amavis. I already used it for filtering inbound mails for spam and virus and since it also works with DKIM signing and checking, well... That just another plus in my book. I updated my answer with the Amavis version. :-)

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation. I'll try working with Amavis.